# django middleware set user special global variable

Tags: django, templates, variables, response, middleware

if every web page has a user new message notice(new message count, like message(1)), how can i pass variable '{ new_message_count: 1}' to every view 
i want to using middleware:

```
class page_variable():
def process_request(self, request):
    # put the variable to the request or response so can used in template variable
    return None
```

and template look like:

```
<a href="/message/">new <em>({{ new_message_count }})</em></a>
```

Answer (score 5):

There's already a built-in [messaging framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/messages/) that handles all of this for you.

However, assuming you really want to roll your own, you can't pass things into the context from middleware. You *can* attach it to the `request` object, which you can then use in your view or template, or add a context processor which takes the variable from the request and adds it into the context.

Comment: yes! that is what i want, many thanks, but how to attach it to the request  ? i try the "request.new_message_count = 1" or "request['new_message_count']=1" or "request.__class__.new_message_count=1", but do not work

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? The first one should work fine.

Comment: i do it at def process_request(self, request): , but the template do not get the variable {{ new_message_count }}, i must miss some thing. i will try again

Comment: If you've attached the variable to the request, then of course you need to access it as `{{ request.new_message_count }}`.

Comment: i want to pass variable like return render_to_response('index.html',
    {},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
and the template using variable {{ new_message_count }}

Comment: But as I clearly explained above, you can't do that from middleware alone.

Comment: hi, i fix the problem. using context_processors, i misunderstand the usage of context_processors and middleware, it is easy write a context_processor like def message_statis(request):
    return {
 'new_message_count': 1,
    }
and direct get the variable {{ new_message_count }} in template, thanks Daniel Roseman, this is my first question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

In the development version of django, you can edit template context from a middleware before rendering:

```
class MessageCountMiddleware:
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        response.context['new_message_count'] = message_count(request.user)
```

In Django 1.2 you can create a custom context processor:

```
def add_message_count(request):
    return { 'new_message_count': message_count(request.user) }
```

and register it in settings

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += [ 'my_project.content_processors.add_message_count' ]
```